# Location tracking issue inside buildings with IP filtered SIM card (NETWORK_PROVIDER)

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location

I am experiencing difficulties obtaining my current location when I am inside a building, and my SIM card is subject to IP filtering. However, when I switch my SIM card to public access, I am able to obtain my location successfully.

I am curious if there are specific IP addresses that I should whitelist in order to acquire my location while indoors within any building?

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    
    String provider = location.getProvider();

    Log.e("Latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));
    Log.e("Longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
    Log.e("provider", provider);

    if (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.equals(provider)) {
        editText1.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
        editText2.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
        editText3.setText(provider);
    } else if (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.equals(provider)) {
        editText4.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
        editText5.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
        editText6.setText(provider);
    }
}
```